# matlab calculating delta between plotted lines

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-integration, delta

I am producing this graph (reduced code version) :

```
k = 1000
r = [100 220 470 1*k 2200 4700 10*k 22*k 47*k 100*k 220*k 470*k 1000*k ]

unModNB = [0.72 0.746 0.801 0.92 1.16 1.69 2.78 4.6 6.45 9.1 11.2 12.4 13.2]
unModWB = [1.124 1.17 1.23 1.48 1.84 2.65 4.2 7.6 11.8 15.4 18.6 20.01 21.7]

ModNBdB = 20*log10( ModNB)
ModWBdB = 20*log10( ModWB)

semilogx( r,  ModNBdB, r, ModWBdB )
grid
legend(Line 1 ', 'Line 2')
```

How am I able to produce another graph of the delta between line 1 and line 2 across intervals of delta across the full scale?

I  want to avoid simply using the reading deltas because of the 'jumpy' graph that this meathod generates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is interpolate between the unModNB and unModWB points and calculate the differences (deltas, as you say) between those. For that you can use `interp1()`. Try this:

```
k = 1000;
r = [100 220 470 1*k 2200 4700 10*k 22*k 47*k 100*k 220*k 470*k 1000*k ];

unModNB = [0.72 0.746 0.801 0.92 1.16 1.69 2.78 4.6 6.45 9.1 11.2 12.4 13.2];
unModWB = [1.124 1.17 1.23 1.48 1.84 2.65 4.2 7.6 11.8 15.4 18.6 20.01 21.7];

ModNBdB = 20*log10( unModNB );
ModWBdB = 20*log10( unModWB );

semilogx( r, ModNBdB, r, ModWBdB )
grid
legend('Line 1', 'Line 2')

sampled_x_vals = linspace(r(1),r(end),1000);

unModNB_sampled = interp1(r, unModNB, sampled_x_vals, 'pchip');
unModWB_sampled = interp1(r, unModWB, sampled_x_vals, 'pchip');

deltas = unModWB_sampled-unModNB_sampled;
figure, semilogx(sampled_x_vals,deltas), grid;
```

If, by 'deltas' you mean something other than difference, please clarify.

Comment: Awesome, I will give that a try when I get back to that. By delta I did indeed mean the difference between the two lines, I intended the phrasing to make it clear that I whished to do whilst, as you have educated me, interpolating.

Many thanks, I will look into understanding what you have done and implementing it in a few hours, will be back to up rep!

Comment: I have examined your code and understand it I think, but was not expecting it to produce what it did.

The graph my code generates has a difference of roughly 4 between the plotted lines at r = 10^2.

The plot your code generates begins at roughly 0.4. By the end it appears to be correct. 

Could this be because of an incorrect form of interpolation ?